# Searching from a stack

Tags: c, data-structures

I am implementing a stack and while it was a no-brainer to implement the basic operations push and pop, I am wondering how to implement somewhat efficient searching. The underlying structure is a linked list

Comment: Stacks do not support searching - if you need to search, a stack is the wrong data structure to use.

Comment: @Neil: But what if the OP *needs* a stack, i.e. LIFO semantics? I don't think he's asking about STL stacks, or Boost stacks, or any other kind of "standard" stack implementation. He says he's "implementing" this stack. Obviously, the implementation can be made to allow efficient searching *and* LIFO semantics at the same time. It just needs an extra data structure (red-black tree or hash table) layered on top of the stack structure.

Comment: Well searching isn't exactly the right word, rather I need to know whether an item is in the stack

Comment: @Dan Then he has some other kind of data structure.

Comment: @Neil: Implementation is not what makes it a stack. It's the interface. So long as it supports push and pop (i.e. has LIFO semantics) then it's a stack. The underlying impl. doesn't matter. If it looks like a stack, and quacks like a stack...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its basic form, a stack would only allow slowish linear searches.  I.e., if the stack has n elements, you would need to search through all n (1/2 n, on average) to find a match.  If your stack is relatively small, this linear (one by one) search might not matter that much.

However, if you have a much larger set, you might be able to combine two data structures together to make searches more efficient:  For example, you could have a hash table *in addition to* the stack: Each time you push something on the stack, you could also add it to the hash table.  Conversely, when you remove it from the stack, you could remove it from the table.  Hash tables allow relatively fast lookups, even with very large data sets-- therefore, your searches could be quite fast.

One problem with my proposed solution is how to properly handle duplicate items: Stacks can hold dups, but hash tables typically don't.  Therefore, you might need to implement some simple reference counting in the hash table: Each time you pop, decrement the count in the hash table-- when the count drops to zero, you can remove it from the hash.

Another similar possibility is to use a "multimap"-- this is similar to a hash table, but would allow duplicates to be handled more easily.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, as I only need to know whether some data is in the stack.

Comment: And as I rethink my algorithms, I come to realize, I don't need even that information, so the entire question is irrelevant.

Thank you for the answer however; more the reason to implement some form of hashmap.

(I'm not experienced with C, but practicing all the time, and I like these kinds of excercises :))

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you implemented a persistent stack (`push` and `pop` returning new stacks while the argument stack continues to exist) or a mutable stack (the stack passed to `push` and `pop` is modified in-place).

In any case, the deepest values are those that change the least often, so a strategy to speed up searching would be to cache the results of previous searches on the deepest 2, 4, 8, ... elements of the stacks you handle. If you implemented a mutable stack, invalidate the cache as suitable (invalidate the cache entries for the first 2^n elements when the stack depth has come below 2^n).

Answer (score 0):

A stack is not designed to be 'searchable'. Of course, you can easily implement searching on the underlying linked list and expose it to the user - but it's no stack anymore then.

Linear-time search in linked list could look like this:

```
listentry* first;

for(first = head; (first=first->next);) {
  if (first->val == value_to_search) {
     // have a match
     return 1;
  }
}
return 0;
```

The 'legal' way to search a stack is 'pop() until the value you're searching for is on the top of the stack'. Please don't do this if you need the stack afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to examine any item in a stack other than the item at the top, you probably shouldn't be using a stack to contain your items. Rethink the choice of your data structure.